# Lua Combining 2 Logitech scripts in 1

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Can someone help me combine these two scripts in one. I tried but couldn't make it work. I'm not very good at this...
I want to use them on Logitech scripting for a game and I wanna make them work together.

```
if IsKeyLockOn(LockKey)then     
 
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)then                 
                                             
        repeat
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(LC)  then               
        seconds=GetRunningTime()
            seconds1= seconds/1000
            Autotag()                   
        NoRecoil()
        
    elseif  IsMouseButtonPressed(Rapidfirebutton) then      
        seconds=GetRunningTime()
            seconds1= seconds/1000
            Autotag()               
        RapidFire() 
            
        end
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)              
    end 
end 
end
```

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)    
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) then
        recoil = not recoil
        spot = not spot
        end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
      if recoil then
         spot = not spot
        repeat          
      PressKey("P")
         Sleep(7)
      ReleaseKey("P")        
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What are `RC`, `LC` and `Rapidfirebutton`?

Comment: Rc and lc its MOUSE_BUTTON ( 1)

Comment: Rapidfirebutton its MOUSE_BUTTON (4)

Comment: So, LMB=recoil, LMB+MB4=rapidfire?

Comment: @egorskriptunoff I will send you the complete file To your e-mail or to any other place you want

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I sent it to your email